# In elasticsearch is it possible to do relevance scoring as well as sorting in the same query

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have 4 fields A, B, C, D in my type.

I want to use fields A and B for relevance scoring and use C and D for sorting purposes.

So if fields A and B contain the term "x AND y" then all the matching documents will be sorted by C and D.

If fields A and B contain the term "x OR y" then all the matching documents will be sorted by C and D.

So most relevant documents by fields A and B appear in the first group and less relevant appear in the last group and within each group the documents are sorted by C and D.

Is is possible to do something like this using elastic search?

Comment: Do you really want to sort with C,D in both cases?

Comment: Yes, that is the requirement.

Comment: I see... Can you give an example for the fields and do you need to change the sorting? E.g. ASC and DESC?

Comment: So lets say the index contains different blog posts. Then field A= title of the post, B = category of the post, C = number of views and D = number of comments. Then C and D are to be sorted in the descending order.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details on the fields. Last questions to clarify things: Do you need for each request e.g. 20 results of each group? Something like this: Response {Group 1: Id1, Id2, Id3, Group 2: Id11, Id12, Id13} or do need more this Response {Id1, Id2, Id3, Id4, Id5, ..., Id11, ...}. Moreover is one of the two sorting fields the primary one?

Comment: I take it `x` and `y` are not unstructured full-text searches, but structured term queries/filters i.e. the field value either matches or it doesn't (no scoring)?